# Does this form letter mean that I didn't get the visa?

Tags: visas, uk, application-status

This is the only email I've received other than Sheffield notifying me that they have received my documents. I just got it today and it addresses me with "Dear Applicant" and not by my full name, I also don't have a reference number, just the GWF number. I'm a bit anxious. Here's the email:

> Reference number: GWF0XXXXXX
>
> Dear Applicant,
>
> Your passport and supporting documentation are now ready for collection at the TLScontact UK Visa Application Centre. You can collect your documents in person or by a representative.
>
> **Collection in person**
>
> Please provide following:
>
> Your Application Checklist
>
> Your Original Photographic ID
>
> Copy of Your Photographic ID
>
> **Collecting using a representative**
>
> Please provide following:
>
> Your Application Checklist
>
> Your Original Photographic ID
>
> Copy of Your Photographic ID
>
> Representative’s Original Photographic ID
>
> Copy of Representative’s Photographic ID
>
> Signed Letter of Authorisation from You (clearly stating the Representative’s details)
>
> You can check collection times and the Centre address on the Address and opening hours page. You are advised to make prompt arrangements to collect your documents from the Visa Application Centre as TLScontact is only able to hold them for 30 days. After this time they will be returned to UK Visas and Immigration, who will pass them on to the issuing authority.
>
> **Return by Courier**
>
> If your documents are being sent back to you by courier, it will be dispatched within 24 business hours. You will receive an additional email from TLScontact to confirm when they have been dispatched. The local courier service provider may also confirm this with you, depending upon which courier is used in your area.
>
> This is a post only email that is not monitored, please do not reply to this address. If you wish to contact us, please check our Contact Us page.
>   The information contained in this communication is privileged and confidential. The content is intended only for the use of the individual or entity named above. If the reader of this message is not the intended recipient, you are hereby notified that any dissemination, distribution or copying of this communication is strictly prohibited. If you have received this communication in error, please notify us immediately by telephone or e-mail, and delete this message from your systems.
>
> Best regards,
>
> TLScontact team
>
> adm.uk.tlscontact.com/ng

Answer (score 44):

**No it doesn’t**. You will be able to tell only when you get your documents back. Even the VAC does not know the decision until then.

This is a generic template to let you know that a decision has been made and the documents are ready for collection/dispatch. It does not indicate the outcome in any way.

Comment: I confirm. I applied for 2 UK visas in 2017. I always got a generic response once they had finished processing my documents. Both of my applications were approved. So there's nothing to worry about until you get your passport back and don't find an issued visa inside.